# Linking a library in g++ doesn't work

Tags: linker, g++

I am trying to compile a .cpp-file which uses a matrix-library. The library-files libnewmat.a and libnewmat.so are in the path /usr/lib64 . The include-files are in path /usr/include/newmat , so I tried (several ways) to compile i.e. with:

```
g++ -I/usr/include -L/usr/lib64 -lnewmat new.cpp -o new3
```

but the compiler doesn't find the library. The content of the .cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <newmat/newmat.h>
#include <newmat/newmatio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
Matrix A(2,2);
Real b[] = {1,2,3,4};
A << b;

cout << A << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The compiler says:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:9: error: ‘Matrix’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘A’
test.cpp:10: error: ‘Real’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b’
test.cpp:11: error: ‘A’ was not declared in this scope
test.cpp:11: error: ‘b’ was not declared in
```

this scope

Could You provide me with the correct c++ code, or the correct command line instruction?

Thanks, Kepler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a library problem - it's a compiler problem - it can't find any definition for Matrix (probably in your include files, but we can't determine that with the information given)

[edit]
Ascertain if your classes in the include files are being referenced correctly
[/edit]

Comment: Thank You,

I forgot 

    using namespace NEWMAT;

That is, because in Netbeans on OpenSuse, where I ran this library before successful, I didn't have to use this namespace.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! :-)

Kepler

Answer (score 1):

If you recently installed this library yourself you probably need to run `sudo ldconfig` to load the so into the linker cache.

EDIT: As Kevin said not a linking error that you're getting.

Perhaps it's a name space issue?
`using namespace NEWMAT;`

according to this: http://www.robertnz.net/nm10.htm#namesp

Comment: I ran sudo ldconfig and tried again. Nothing changed.
Is there a specific folder in which I have to run ldconfig?

Comment: The problem is long before the linker/loader

Comment: Indeed its a compile error not a link error. My head is asleep :S. Perhaps the Matrix and Real classes are wrapped in a namespace?

Comment: http://www.robertnz.net/nm10.htm#namesp  Not sure if you compiled it with that enabled or not.